# Can't change credentials (root, neither other user) via environment variables using docker compose command

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

This is how I start MySQL docker container from docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.9'

   services:
      mysql_db:
        image: mysql
        environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root123
          MYSQL_USER: my_user_1
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: pwd_1
        restart: always
        volumes:
          - db_vol:/var/lib/mysql
        ports:
          - "3306:3306"
          - "33060:33060"
   volumes:
      db_vol:
```

The password for root is NOT changed => the default pwd: "root" for user root works.
Leave alone creating the other MYSQL_USER: user_1 with his password.

I can view the server status via for instance MySQL Workbench using default creds: root/root

The server status is green - running and when I click the Users and Privileged pane, this is what I see:

[image]

So there is another user1, instead of my_user_1 which I have created.

HOWEVER: When I run the container from cmd line like this:

> docker run -d --rm -p 3306:3306 -p 33060:33060 -e
> MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root123 --name=mysql_db mysql:latest

This also works even for user deli1

> docker run -d --rm -p 3306:3306 -p 33060:33060 -e
> MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root123 -e MYSQL_USER=deli1 -e
> MYSQL_PASSWORD=deli_pwd  --name=mysql_db mysql:latest

I do not want to use config files (shared via docker volumes to the container) to override default parameters of MySQL container. Instead, I'd like to use handy environment variables, which I read all around that works nice.. What could be I doing wrong ?

Ubuntu 22.04.1  using VSCode Version: 1.75.1

Date: 2023-02-08T21:35:30.018Z
Electron: 19.1.9
Chromium: 102.0.5005.194
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.23-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.15.0-60-generic
Sandboxed: No

Comment: Did you start the database, then add the environment variable, and then re-ran `docker-compose up -d`?  In that case the original password will be stored in the database data volume, and the changed environment variable isn't considered.

Comment: @DavidMaze I am not sure what you mean. I have a docker-compose.yml script, where I have more dependencies (other containers link this MySQL container).
All I do is docker compose up and down. I do not see why changed env. variables should not be considered - other than another docker bug, or unintended obfuscation...

Comment: The various database images have entrypoint wrapper scripts that check to see if the persistent storage already contains a database, and if it doesn't, intiailizes it.  Those environment variables are only considered when that first-time initialization is done, you can't use them to change the password or other setup on a database that already exists.

Comment: @DavidMaze Yaba-daba-doo ! That's precise nail-hit ! 
Please make it an answer. I had to actually purge the DB volume to get updated creds:
_docker volume rm db_vol_